# How can I break string creation over several lines, but include inline comments

Tags: python, string, comments

I want to create a string, but include comments for each part. In Python, I can do this inside the function `print`, but I can't do it if I'm creating a variable.

```
print("Hello "  + # WORKS
       "World!")

greeting = "Hello " + # FAILS
           "World!"

print(greeting)
```

Throws the error:

> ```
>   File "space.py", line 4
>     greeting = "Hello " + # FAILS
>                                 ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

I tried line continuation:

```
greeting = "Hello " + \# FAILS
           "World!"

print(greeting)
```

> ```
>   File "line_continuation.py", line 4
>     greeting = "Hello " + \# FAILS
>                                  ^
> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630835/python-comments-after-backslash ??

Comment: @DSLima90 Somewhat similar, but backslashes was just one thing that I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have control over spaces you can simply do:

```
print("This "  # comment 1
      "is "  # comment 2
      "a "  # comment 3
      "test")  # comment 4

s = ("This "  # comment 1
     "is "  # comment 2
     "a "  # comment 3
     "test")  # comment 4
print(s)
```

Outputs:

```
This is a test
This is a test
```

Using comma will add a space between each string and is specific to `print`. The method shown above works for strings in general anywhere.

Note that this will represent a single string, so if you want to inject variables you need to `.format` on the last line.

The practice of using `()` around strings are often confused with making a `tuple`, but it's not a tuple unless it contains a comma.

```
s = ("Hello")
print(type(s), s)
s = ("Hello",)
print(type(s), s)
```

Outputs:

```
<class 'str'> Hello
<class 'tuple'> ('Hello',)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can break a string into multiple lines by simply putting them one after the other:

```
a = ("hello " # can use comments
    "world")
print(a)

b = "hello " "world" # this also works
print(b)

c = a " again" # but this doesn't, SyntaxError
print(c)
```

Comment: You need to enclose the string with ``()`` thought. This will yield a syntax error.

Comment: @Grimmy nice catch, only for the multiline one though, single line works just fine without parenthesis.

Comment: yeah it took me maybe two years before I picked up that ("hello") is a string and ("hello",) is a tuple. Even added it to my answer. So easy to mess that up.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Adding parentheses around the parts of the string being constructed works:

```
print("Hello "  + # WORKS
       "World!")

greeting =("Hello " + # WORKS TOO
           "World!")

print(greeting)
```

Comment: By "commas" do you mean "parentheses"?

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks! I totally know the difference. Don't know why I wrote "commas".