# Why can't comments appear after a line continuation character?

Tags: python

Why does Python not allow a comment after a line continuation "\" character, is it a technical or stylistic requirement?

According to the docs [(2.1.5)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining):

> A line ending in a backslash cannot carry a comment.

and [(2.1.3)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#comments):

> A comment signifies the end of the logical line unless the implicit
> line joining rules are invoked. Comments are ignored by the syntax.

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments) does discourage inline comments so I can see how this may stylistically be "unpythonic." I could also see how the "\" could be ambiguous if it allowed comments (should the interpreter ignore *all* subsequent tokens or just comments?) but I think a distinction could easily be made.

Coming from Javascript and accustomed to the fluid interface style, I prefer writing chains like the following instead of reassignment:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)\
        .interleave(special_sauce_fn)\
        .shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)\
        .batch(batch_size)\
        .prefetch()\
        .cache()
```

Instead of

```
dataset = dataset.interleave(special_sauce_fn)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch()
dataset = dataset.cache()
```

While this example is rather self-explanatory, at times I feel like a contextual comment could enhance readability of the code.

Comment: Do you know you could just wrap the whole expression in parentheses to turn on automatic line continuation? Plus, comments work inside that.

Comment: I did not! Thank you.

Comment: Note that method chaining is "fluent", not reactive.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, updated. I was first introduced to this style with react, which I suppose does not even require it although it benefits significantly from it.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to put comments in multiline code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17630835/4518341) [I just edited its title btw.]

Comment: I have never seen line continuation character used like that in source code. I like more like the answer below where one would use parenthesis. I find it easier to read

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the same reason you can't have whitespace after the backslash. It simplifies the parsing, as it can simply remove any backslash-newline pairs before doing any more parsing. If there were spaces or comments after the backslash, there's no backslash-newline sequence to remove.

Answer (score 42):

Generally, line-continuation characters are discouraged. Instead, use parentheses:

```
dataset = (
      tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
        .interleave(special_sauce_fn) #  comment to your
        .shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size) #  heart's delight
        .batch(batch_size)
        .prefetch()
        .cache()
)
```

Comment: I did not know that dots can be on different lines.
Cool

Comment: @TUSqasi It's only because the lines are all contained within a set of parentheses. Outside of some kind of grouper, you can't, sadly. Luckily, as this answer is implying, you can use parentheses for this type of thing quite often.